# Tables created with Peewee seem to disappear into thin air

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, flask, peewee

I'm currently writing a flask app using the `peewee` orm for `postgresql`. It's worked fine in the past, but it seems like something has been thrown into disarray and I'm unclear on how exactly to proceed in debugging the problem.

First I start up the database like so:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

I create a new database:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb indico
```

configure the connection like so:

```
db = peewee.PostgresqlDatabase(
'indico',
host="/tmp/",
user = 'indico', # There is also an indico user, this is not a db name confusion
password = 'password',
)
```

Create the needed tables:

```
class PostgresqlModel(peewee.Model):
    """A base model that will use our Postgresql database"""
    _id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
PostgresqlModel.create_table()
```

But then when I try to actually access the created tables:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -d indico -U indico
>>> \dt
no relations found
```

Nothing seems to show up. If I try to create them again I get an error saying the relation already exists, and while I'm able to save objects, I cannot retrieve them.

I feel like I've done something silly here with my paths and configuration, but I can't seem to figure it out, and I haven't been able to find documentation on the proper introspection I should be doing here. Not looking for a magic fix, but if someone could point me in the right direction it would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that this is a sublety of `peewee`'s autocommit behavior. If autocommit is set to False, then any database created, will only be accessible within the active database commit. Thus, if you create the databases when the module is imported.

Adding `db.commit()` to the end of the `create_table` sequence seems to fix this problem.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    User.create_table()
    db.commit()
```

Comment: When you instantiate your database (in issue description) it doesn't look like you set `autocommit=False`, so I'm confused why autocommit would be False.